# Duda sobre un select option y javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo una pequeña duda, resulta que tengo algo como esto:

```
<select id="target">
    <option value="2"> *Quiero auto seleccionar este* </option>
    <option value="3">...</option>
    <option selected disabled hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>
```

Lo que quiero es simular un "click" el cual debería auto seleccionar una opcion al momento de cargar la pagina.

Actualmente tengo algo como esto:

```
    const firstChild = document.querySelector('#target').firstChild
    if(firstChild){
        firstChild.click()
    }
```

Pero no funciona, lo de asignarle el valor de la opción al select no me sirve, ya que al hacerle click a la opción esta "rellena" unos campos en un formulario, por lo tanto, solamente debería funcionarme simulando un click en la opción.

Debe ser en JS sin jquery

Alguien sabrá como solucionarlo ?

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: quieres setear un valor de las opciones en el select al cargar la pagina?

Comment: Así es, es para auto seleccionar la primera "direccion" guardada y al hacerle click a esta dirección se auto completan otros campos en un formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar la propiedad `selected` a `'true'`.

```
<select id="target">
    <option id="default" value="2"> *Quiero auto seleccionar este* </option>
    <option value="3">...</option>
    <option selected disabled hidden>Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>
```

Le otorgamos una ID para poderlo sacar en el código por el DOM.

```
const first = document.querySelector(`#default`);

if (first) {
    first.selected = 'true';
}
```

De este modo podremos seleccionarlo cuando queramos.

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes seleccionar el select y setear el `value` al valor de la opción que quieras setear.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('target')
select.value = 3
```

```html
<select id="target">
    <option value="2"> *Quiero auto seleccionar este* </option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```